# Mongo enterprise installation Error in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, installation, ubuntu-20.04

I have updated recently to Ubuntu 20.04 and facing problems while installing MongoDb enterprise.

```
digvj@digvj:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-enterprise
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-enterprise : Depends: mongodb-enterprise-server but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also on running the command where i have specified every package of mongo it is showing this error:

```
digvj@digvj:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-enterprise=4.2.6 mongodb-enterprise-server=4.2.6 mongodb-enterprise-shell=4.2.6 mongodb-enterprise-mongos=4.2.6 mongodb-enterprise-tools=4.2.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-enterprise-server : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
                             Depends: libsnmp30 (>= 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.3~dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Inspect the output of ` apt-get install -y mongodb-enterprise-server` for clues.

Comment: It gives me this that it depends on some dependencies which is not present in Ubuntu 20.04, described in question edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the issue in MongoDb Zira issues and got the solution over there.
Here is the link to that:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-48316

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB provides binary packages for some operating systems. Ubuntu 20.04 is not an operating system that the packages are available for.

You *may* be able to get MongoDB running on 20.04 by downloading and installing the packages it wants manually (for example,  [libsnmp30](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libsnmp30) and [libsensors4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libsensors4)).

If there has been, for example,  a C library upgrade between 18.04 and 20.04, the 18.04 packages may not be usable on a 20.04 system, and this won't work.

If the question is for a production environment and you are using the enterprise edition of MongoDB you should probably stick with the supported operating systems like Ubuntu 18.04. If this is for a development environment, you could run MongoDB in Ubuntu 18.04 in Docker.

Comment: How can i install these manually as while trying to do so i am unable to. I have tried using command sudo apt-get install packgname

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line